# Significance of categorical variable in a linear model

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, p-value, model, linear

I am slightly confused in creating a linear model with a categorical variable. In this model my outcome variable is student performance (GPA) and the categorical contains three different courses students have taken.

From the output, only one of the courses is significant. Does this mean I can take the categorical variable to be significant as a whole? Or would all the courses need to be significant?

Further to that, does the fact that the intercept is significant mean that my baselines course is also significant?

Thanks for any assistance...just a bit unsure with this.

[image: Linear model]

Answer (score 0):

To determine whether the categorical variable is significant as a whole you need to perform an ANOVA, where you will get one statistic per categorical variable.

For the interpretation, the model is telling you that the first course (the one in the intercept) is (statistically) different from zero (for a certain $\alpha$), and the last course (Y) is (statistically) different from the first course. (while course A is not statistically different from the first course)

Answer (score 0):

To test for differences between any of the courses (i.e., to conduct an overall test):

```
fit <- lm(GPA ~ Course, data=stats_anx_start)
anova(fit)
```

In your output, the t-test for the intercept term has no meaning. Only tests for differences between courses are meaningful.

See user2974951's answer for interpretation of the other two t-tests in your output.